# Iterate twice on bash scripts arguments using getoptex

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

I'm writing a bash script that needs long arguments, like `--argument` and not only letters like `-a`. There is a function called `getoptex` which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MisterDA/7284755) that can handle this.

The thing is, my project is very specific as it is modular. A single script is called, and then I need to iterate on the arguments to find an option that would tell me to source another script, which has specific options and needs to parse the arguments again. There are around five differents subscripts, each ones whith their own options.

But the first iteration on `$@` seems to erase every arguments and options (but leaves the arguments without options), so I can't parse it twice !

I'm giving a code sample for you to see what I've done.

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./getopt.sh

echo "$@"

while getoptex "a; b;" "$@"
do
    if [ "$OPTOPT" = "a" ]; then
        echo "a"
    elif [ "$OPTOPT" = "b" ]; then
        echo "b"
    fi
done
shift $[OPTIND-1]
for arg in "$@"
do
    echo "$arg"
done

OPTIND=1
unset OPTOFS

echo "$@"

while getoptex "a; b;" "$@"
do
    if [ "$OPTOPT" = "a" ]; then
        echo "a"
    elif [ "$OPTOPT" = "b" ]; then
        echo "b"
    fi
done
shift $[OPTIND-1]
for arg in "$@"
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

But it never parses the second time... Any idea ?

Comment: If you really need to preserve the arguments, remove them, then reset them, use an array to store a copy of the arguments:  `saved_args=( "$@" ); ...mess with $@...; set -- "${saved_args[@]}"; ...arguments restored to original state...`.  You may need to work out how to reset the workings of `getoptex` -- it looks to me as though `OPTIND=0` will do that for you, but I may be misreading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the first call to `shift`. Usually, you use that to remove the arguments that you've already parsed, but since you want to parse them twice, you *don't* want to remove any after the first pass.

By the way, `$[OPTIND-1]` is obsolete; use `$((OPTIND-1))` instead.

Comment: Perfect ! This works great.
The only problem (that I don't have, but that could happen) is that the shift was used to seperate options and their respective arguments from a final list of arguments, like a bunch of files. In this case maybe the Jonathan Leffer solution would be best.

I just realized that the `getoptex` function was written in 1997. Do you think that it is completely obsolete ? It is still part of bash-doc pkg...

Comment: That's true; I don't use `getopt` much (and never used `getoptex`, which I presume works similarly), and had forgotten that the `shift` works because the arguments are rearranged.